# query sqlite3 database multiple tables

Tags: iphone, sqlite

In the example below uses a single database table (Animals), which contains three columns (name, description, photo).

If my database contains two tables (1.animals, 2.Cities), each with its columns (name, description, photo), how do I ask for eg. "names Cities", which is positioned in column 1 table 2 .,in combination with "animal description",positioned in table 1 column 2,to make an object with these "values".

referncing this.....(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)....

Thank you.

```
    // Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "select * from animals";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row
            NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

            // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
            Animal *animal = [[Animal alloc] initWithName:aName description:aDescription url:aImageUrl];
```

Comment: beside your question, use fmdb, a great SQLite3 Objective-C Wrapper. https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns of both tables are `name`, `description` and `photo`, I don't see a relationship between them. Anyway, here's an SQL statement that does what you're asking for, but it doesn't make much sense:

```
SELECT c.name, a.description FROM Cities AS c, animals AS a;
```

If I have misunderstood your question let me know.

Comment: You understand my question .
I rebuilt the question to make sense.
Table1 (animals) with columns (1name, 2description, 3photo) and Table2 (cities)with columns (1hotels, 2bars, 3pubs).

Give me the query for this please.
And tell me what number should be put for 3pubs or 1hotels ,instead of x:    
      (char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, x)

Thank you very much.